# IE Invalid Argument Error - Says it is an error in jQuery, but I don't think so

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-7, invalid-argument

I am pulling my hairs out over an invalid argument error in IE7, maybe all IE's...

The site is: http://www.karencaldwelldesign.com/fashion

IE says it is an error on line 12, but if I open up Script Debugger it says the problem is with some code in jQuery.  I don't buy that.

So, I looked at my script (http://www.caldwellsnyder.com/__data/assets/js_file/0003/5943/kc-gallery.js) and line 65 seems to be the problem:

```
data = '<div id="content'+id+'" class="content">'+data+'</div>';
```

data is returned from the jQuery $.ajax() function, but I needed to wrap it with an additional numbered div.

In particular it is the id variable that is caused the invalid argument error, but I have no idea why!  The var is just a number that gets incremented.  Removing the var from that line lets the page load perfectly, but I really need to increment the id in this way.

Does anyone have any idea why this simple variable would be cause invalid argument in IE?

Comment: `id = id+'';` this doesnt look right for incrementing id

Comment: Sorry, that was just part of my testing I forgot to remove.  The bug is still an issue without that.

Comment: @Nic: in one part of your code you are passing `data` as a context parameter to `$`, and then in another you are concatenating it with a string. What does `data` hold exactly?

Comment: @Crecent: data holds just some divs and images.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somehow you're ending up trying to set a width of `-5px`; IE doesn't like that. That value is coming from the line `$this.css(cssToApply);` in JScrollPane.js which gets it from calculating the variable `realPaneWidth`:

```
var realPaneWidth = paneWidth - settings.scrollbarWidth - settings.scrollbarMargin - p;
```

In that, `paneWidth` and `settings.scrollbarWidth` both equal 676, and settings.scrollbarMargin is 5, giving you -5 (p is zero).

In `kc-gallery.js` you appear to be initialising jScrollPane with the value of 676 for `scrollbarWidth` in the function `applyScroll`. This is called from the setInterval function assigned to the variable `check_images`, and that takes us all the way back up the call stack from the place where IE actually errors on setting `width` to `-5px`.

So it's definitely something to do with the way you're using JScrollPane. You may want to check the documentation for any tips - I've never used that plugin myself, so I'm afraid I can't help with that. However, a `scrollbarWidth` value of 676 seems a little excessive... [according to the JScrollPane docs](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html):

> **scrollbarWidth** [int] - the width of the created scrollbar in pixels (defaults to 10)

Comment: You are right, this is definitely the issue here.  But, I am really needing to have the scroll bar width that wide, because I would like to turn an entire image into the scroll area, so clicking the bottom half would allow you to scroll the image down.

Comment: If the scroll bar is that wide, there won't be any space left to display the image. Imagine if you set the scroll bar of the browser window to occupy the full width of the window: you wouldn't be able to see the content, just an enormously wide scroll bar where the content should be. Still, if you subtract `settings.scrollbarMargin` from the value you pass in as `scrollbarWidth` then you'll avoid triggering the IE error, as you'll be setting `realPaneWidth` to zero.

Comment: I had a similar issue - I fixed it by checking if the new width that was being dynamically set was actually a number: if(!isNaN(emWidth)){ }

Answer (score 0):

The error you are seeing comes from jQuery when you try to set a DOM attribute to a value that is invalid. For example try setting a z-index to NaN or a string. IE errors on this where firefox and other browsers just ignore the value.

You can see an example of this by dropping the following line in to the console on this page in IE8 or using [Jash](http://billyreisinger.com/jash/) for earlier versions: `jQuery("#header").css("z-index", NaN);`

It looks like your variable glob_index is becoming undefined at some point, thus jQuery errors when trying to set the z-index of a DOM node to this.